# Milisegundos en KOTLIN/JAVA

Tags: java, kotlin, date

Cada cierto tiempo quiero que suceda algo, Handler().postDelayed funciona pero no puedo pausar el tiempo.
Intenté hacerlo con el método ***when*** y no me sale.

```
val start : TextView = findViewById(R.id.start)

    when(System.currentTimeMillis()){
         1000L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         1250L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         1500L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         1750L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         2000L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         2250L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         2500L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         2750L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
```

Este el el XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

Comment: Pero... tú has mirado qué devuelve `System.currentTimeMillis()`???? Porque devuelve la hora actual en milisegundos... jamás va a ser 1000, si no que el valor será de varios miles de millones, por ejemplo, esto acabo de recogerlo en java: `1684865970248`. Lo primero que se debe hacer **SIEMPRE** es mirar qué valor tienen las variables que estás usando... hay que aprender a debugar (aunque si mirases la documentación lo habrías visto igualmente)! Lo mejor es que hagas algo como `val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()` y en tu when lo uses como `currentTime + 1000`, `currentTime + 1250`...

Comment: @Benito-B gracias por ayudarme, intente hacerlo  pero no me sale, tengo este error: Incompatible types: `val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  when(currentTime + 1000){      
   start.visibility -> View.INVISIBLE
} `

Comment: Por favor, añade lo que te piden en los comentarios yendo a [edit]. En los comentarios el código y los logs son infumables. Además, decir _no me sale_ en la pregunta no es la mejor descripción. Personalmente creo que es la peor opción porque no describe la cosa. ;)

Comment: currentTime es un Long, 1000 lo estás usando como int. No copies y pegues sin más, piensa en qué está haciendo el código. Antes tenías el when con los números en formato Long! (`1000L`). Probaste a ponerlo igual? Preguntar en SO debería ser el **último recurso**, no lo primero que se hace...

Comment: Le agregue el formato Long a  (`1000L`) pero el error continua, no logro entenderte, disculpame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, es difícil que al obtener el valor de `System.currentTimeMillis()` , pueda llamarse alguna opción de tu `when`, ya que la longitud de este valor no correspondería, este es un ejemplo del valor obtenido por `System.currentTimeMillis()`: `1684956002499L`, por lo tanto, sería difícil que pudiera entrar a alguna de las opciones:

```
       when(System.currentTimeMillis()){
         1000L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         1250L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         1500L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         1750L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         2000L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         2250L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         2500L -> start.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
         2750L -> start.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
```

Debes tomar en cuenta la longitud del valor, y te sugiero también declarar rangos en la forma:

```
when(valor){
     in valor1..valor2 -> println("Opción: 1")
     in valor3..valor4 -> println("Opción: 2")
     else -> Log.i(TAG, "Opción: 10 valor: $time")
}
```

Al definir dentro de un `when` valores de tipo `Long` no es necesario agregar el sufijo "L".

Ejemplo:

```
 when(System.currentTimeMillis()){
            in 1684951000000..1684952000000 -> println("Opción: 1")
            in 1684952000000..1684953000000 -> println("Opción: 2")
            in 1684953000000..1684954000000 -> println("Opción: 3")
            in 1684954000000..1684955000000 -> println("Opción: 4")
            in 1684955000000..1684956000000 -> println("Opción: 5")
            in 1684956000000..1684957000000 -> println("Opción: 6")
            in 1684957000000..1684958000000 -> println("Opción: 7")
            in 1684958000000..1684959000000 -> println("Opción: 8")
            in 1684959000000..1684960000000 -> println("Opción: 9")
            else -> println("Opción: 10 valor: $time")
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, tu respuesta fue clara y útil! Era lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Hola @DanielIvan me da gusto que fue de ayuda, saludos.